# Returning an array populated by promise.all()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've constructed the array "newPlanets" using api calls alongside with Promise.all

```
export function api_calling(){
  var newPlanets = [];
  const URLs = fetching() // function that returns an array of fetches
  Promise.all(URLs).then(data => {
    // push all "results" field into newPlanets
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        newPlanets.push(data[i].results[n]);
      }
    }
  })
  return newPlanets;
}
```

However, when returning it to another function which calls it:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    let data = api_calling()
    console.log(data)
    super(props);
  }
}
```

console shows an empty array. How would I be able to return the constructed array into my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promises will resolve asynchronously, so you can't write `let data = api_calling()` in the constructor.

You could instead return the result of `Promise.all` from `api_calling` and set the component state when it has resolved in `componentDidMount`.

**Example**

```
function api_calling() {
  const URLs = fetching();

  return Promise.all(URLs).then(data => {
    var newPlanets = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        newPlanets.push(data[i].results[n]);
      }
    }

    return newPlanets;
  });
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { data: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    api_calling().then(data => {
      this.setState({ data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and when console logging right before this.setState, console is still showing undefined

Comment: @IMTRYING Did you notice the change in `api_calling` as well? You need to return the `Promise.all`, and also return `newPlanets` inside the `then` callback.

Comment: sorry, I missed out on the return newPlanets part, thanks!